# Why Conditional Expressions Don't Match in the gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

Here is the code

```
stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE
    - if [[ "$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE" =~ /^v?\d+\.\d+\.\d+.*$/ ]]; then echo "Match found"; else echo "No match found"; fi
```

Print results

```
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:00
$ echo $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE
v0.1.1
$ if [[ "$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE" =~ /^v?\d+\.\d+\.\d+.*$/ ]]; then echo "Match found"; else echo "No match found"; fi
No match found
Job succeeded
```

I've tried optimising regular expressions but it doesn't work，Are there other more effective methods of matching?